# What to do if Host is not willing to increase group_concat_max_len

Tags: php, mysql

I have a shared hosting and don't have privileges to edit group_concat_max_len. A lot of my queries return truncated results. What to do aside from upgrading to dedicated hosting, which is way more expensive.
Host does not want to hear anything but me shelling more bucks to get a dedicated server...any options?

Thanks

Comment: Probably return the columns, and concatenate the results with PHP by building up a new result set, most likely.

Comment: You already tried set this in your current MySQL session, not global --> for example `SET @@session.group_concat_max_len = 10000;`?

Comment: @Martin I will give this a go asap again. Last time it failed but I didn't put it right before the actual query and from what I read, I should. Will let you know how it went.

Comment: It turned out there is no way for me to bypass the default 1024 limit so results still get truncated. Just stumbled upon `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` which I may use to purposely limit the output of  `GROUP_CONCAT()` to show "top N results". 
Far from perfect but at least results should not get truncated they way they are now.

Comment: @aynber I like your idea but wouldn't concatenating with PHP return only one row?
Or is there a way to concatenate and still fetch all rows like with `group_concat()`?
I only know how to concatenate like:
`echo $row['column1']. "some text string". $row['column2'];`

Comment: It depends on how you do it. If you iterate through the results, you can build up an array with the fields/concatenated fields you want. So `$array = []; while($row = (getresultset)) {  $array[] = [ 'field1' => $row['field1'], 'field2' => $row['field2'], 'fullname' => $row['first_name']. ' '.$row['last_name']]; }`